# Group list items by field value in the Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to group the items in the `Django admin` app by a specific field (e.g. `date`).
So I've added to the queryset in `admin.ModelAdmin.getQueryset()` the following:

```
queryset = queryset.values('date').annotate(Sum('amount'))
```

But this doesn't work because in this case, a `dict` is returned instead of a `queryset`.

I started exploring what's inside the `django/contrib/admin` folder, and I think something need to be done before sending the object to the template `change_list.html`.

I'm not sure but I think the class in `views/main.py` (admin folder) might need some change.

Can anybody confirm that what I'm trying to do is achievable at all?

Please find below a representation of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can use {% regroup %} templatetag in html if you know how to override django admin default templates

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR I completely forgot about the `regroup` tag. Do you have any idea which `templatetag` or `template` file contains the items to group? (I can't find them in `change_list.html`).

Comment: how you want output in django admin? means how it will show in admin? can you add any demo image what output you want?

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR I've just updated the question with an image representing what I'm trying to achieve. Basically I need to have `dates` followed by separate tables for items having that date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the below example in URL. it's has great way to understand with override django admin with custom queryset and groupby data
https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-turn-django-admin-into-a-lightweight-dashboard-a0e0bbf609ad

Answer (score 1):

I found this useful: https://github.com/xacce/django_admin_grouper

You can simply define the group in `ClassAdmin`

```py
class RecordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def regroup_by(self):
        return 'category'
```

The repo overrides Django's `change_list_results.html`. If your `RecordAdmin` has method `reggroup_by` than it inserts a row with the name of the category. If `reggroup_by` is missing it works as usual.